# how to write a query in pl/sql to identify cyclic relations in the data

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have the data in the following manner where `A` is the parent of `B`, `B` is the parent of `C`, `C` is the parent of `D` and `A` is the child of `D`.  How do I identify such irregular data in the table using an SQL query?

```
+--------+-------+
| parent | child |
+--------+-------+
| A      | B     |
| B      | C     |
| C      | D     |
| D      | A     |
+--------+-------+
```

Comment: read up on CONNECT BY

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this exactly what you want, however I'll give it a try:

```
with 
mydata as 
 (
  select  'A' as par, 'B' as ch from dual
   union all
  select  'B' as par, 'C' as ch from dual
   union all
  select  'C' as par, 'D' as ch from dual
   union all
  select  'D' as par, 'A' as ch from dual
 ), 
 mypaths as 
   (
   SELECT sys_connect_by_path(par,'/') AS par,ch
   FROM mydata
   CONNECT BY nocycle par = PRIOR ch
   )
select * from mypaths 
where par like '%'||ch||'%'
```

this gives results such as:

```
par         ch  
/A/B/C/D    A
/B/C/D/A    B
/C/D/A/B    C
/D/A/B/C    D
```